# sqlalchemy - force it to NEVER commit?

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy

I'm using fixtures with SQLAlchemy to create some integration tests.

I'd like to put SQLAlchemy into a "never commit" mode to prevent changes ever being written to the database, so that my tests are completely isolated from each other. Is there a way to do this?

My initial thoughts are that perhaps I could replace `Session.commit` with a mock object; however I'm not sure if there are other things that might have the same effect that I also need to mock if I'm going to go down that route.

Comment: are you sure you need this?  Would an in-memory sqlite database work for your needs?

Comment: @IfLoop Yes, I need this. No, in-memory sqlite will not help here, not lease because our database schema is very much tied to using DB2.

Comment: @Marcin Consider another approach - using `setup` and `teardown` to do the cleanup. Otherwise you will rely on behaviour of tested code, which could do something wrong.

Comment: In other transaction models I've seen this as `transaction.doom()`, e.g. in [ZODB](http://svn.zope.org/ZODB/trunk/src/transaction/tests/doom.txt?revision=70066&pathrev=70066) or `pyramid_tm`. Looking at [`sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction), I don't think it supports it.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Right, however `session.rollback()` is having no effect in my tests. I'm certainly open to any approach that can provide complete isolation for each test, but it must be implemented through (or by subverting) sqlalchemy.

Comment: @Marcin I was thinking of complete recreation of the database.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Unfortunately, that's not possible, for time reasons. Hence why I'd like complete transaction isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scoped session manager will by default return the same session object for each connection. Accordingly, one can replace `.commit` with `.flush`, and have that change persist across invocations to the session manager.

That will prevent commits.

To then rollback all changes, one should use `session.transaction.rollback()`.