# SQLAlchemy prevent commit (in test) or test mode

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have a python library that hooks into an existing Rails database. During testing, I would like to be able to prevent committing to the DB ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394785/sqlalchemy-force-it-to-never-commit)).

Ideally `session.commit()` would only do `flush()` so that a `rollback()` can be called, but only in testing. Effectively the whole tests runs in a transaction so there is no leakage between test suites.

The standard method of testing with sqlalchemy is to create and drop all tables, but Rails relies on the tables existing for specs.

Or, perhaps I have a lack of understanding of good Python/Alchemy practices, that I should be writing my libraries such that I `commit()` only at the last moment?